# What protocol should I use for server to client communication?

Tags: android, rest, client-server

We are creating a device with `android TV OS` (`Android - 9 PIE`). We have changed/removed some parts in OS like play-store, default launcher etc. We build one apk as launcher and this will call others apks.

The device use wi-fi for internet access. We have web application(`ASP.NET MVC Webpage`) that will list all available apk’s for our device. User can login using their credential then select the apk and request to install to the device. Device are linked with user’s ID.

Here I have 2 questions as follow

1. How I ping / send some information directly to the client from
   server (client doesn’t have static IP)?
2. How I send apk file from server to client (without client request)?

Answer (score 1):

For the first, look into push messaging.  Firebase cloud messaging is a common implementation of that.

For the second, you really can't- an apk is too big for any push messaging implementation I know of.  What you can do is ping the client with a message that will then tell the client to download the apk from the server.  So one step removed.